# List of silverlight limitations / restrictions

Tags: .net, silverlight, runtime

I have seen and heard of various Silverlight restrictions, e.g. file I/O restrictions, some reflection limitations, restrictions on which languages can be used, printing, resolution, etc.

Could you please compile a list of all major silverlight limitations, as compared to a full-blown .NET application? This is for the latest version (4.0).

I'm not asking for a class reference, but high-level features. It would be nice to propose some workarounds too, if any, but this is not essential.

Many thanks

Comment: Do you have some specific libraries in mind that you would normally work with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another bunch of restrictions *(btw some of these problems you can bypass using out-of-browser (OOB) mode with elevated trust + automation with WScript.Shell)*:

1. You can't interact with registry
2. You can't interact with file system.
   Only with library folders (like
   Music, Videos, Pictures)
3. You can't use DllImport.
4. You can't use non generic
   collections from System.Collections
   namespace.
5. If you decide to use linux version
   of Silverlight (Moonlight) then you
   can't use OOB at all
6. You can't call services synchronously (only async calls available).
7. You can't get synchronous response from HttpWebRequest.
8. Silverlight doesn't implement MD5 hashing. ([custom MD5 implementation for Silverlight](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SilverlightMD5))
9. Silverlight doesn't implement RSA encription algorithm (there was nice web site with [RSA algorithm implementation for Silverlight](http://riawebsoft.ru/Silverlight/Rsa/TestEnglish.aspx). But looks like it is down for now.)
10. Silverlight doesn't implement Rijndael encription algorithm (for backward compability you may use AES algorithm with block size = 128)
11. Silverlight doesn't support ASCII/ANSI encodings.
12. Silverlight doesn't support 3D objects drawing (you may use [Kit3D](http://kit3d.codeplex.com/) or [Balder](http://balder.codeplex.com/) instead).

But there are some good news. For example you still can use OOB Silverlight for OSX application).

Comment: Nice, if you can complete the list I will accept it as answer.

Comment: Sure, why not :)
I've updated my post with newly found Silverlight restrictions. Also if I'll find some new restrictions I'll add them to my post.

Answer (score 3):

Its probably easier to list what is **in** Silverlight than what is **not**.  To do that you could look through the Silverlight documentation.

However here are a few links into the documentation which list some the key issues:-

[WPF Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903925(v=VS.95).aspx)
[Silverlight Application Security Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470128(v=VS.95).aspx)
[HTTP Communication and Security with Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838250(v=VS.95).aspx)
[URL Access Restrictions in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189008(v=VS.95).aspx)
[Network Security Access Restrictions in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(v=VS.95).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are running as a full trust application you don't have access to the local file system. This is a perfectly reasonable restriction for a web application though.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you will find this relavant or not but i used WPF DataGrid and hated it because it had a property that when it was in invalid state it wont exit edit mode and because of that many exception arose.

Answer (score 0):

- Printing is actually generated using a bitmap that is 600 DPI; no raster-based text or graphics resulting in jagged content upon close examination
- No ability to create resizeable child windows, though you can use Tim Heuer's [floatable Window](http://floatablewindow.codeplex.com/) as an alternative
- No ability to use an MDI interface
- No double-click, though you can use [threads with timers](http://www.michaelsnow.com/2010/05/10/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-17-double-click/) to simulate this
- No support for WPF's IMultiValueConverter, though you can use [this](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/05/silverlight-multibinding-solution-for-silverlight-4/) as an alternative option
- No ability to prevent the screensaver from kicking in
- Mousewheel support varies across platform/browser
- No support for WS-Trust
- WCF support is limited to basic http binding

Answer (score -2):

It's more hassle than it's worth.  Too many restrictions to count.